# Fewer codes but with many database queries or many codes but with fewer database queries?

Tags: php, mysql

There are two options I want to take one of them:

1. Writing fewer codes but with many database queries.
2. Writing many codes but with fewer database queries.

Dependence on the database in everything, or if you found ways but not the best to make you avoid using the database. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: This is completely dependent on the code in question, the queries in question, the database, the goal, the weather and the day of the month. In other words: this question is impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: @Nanne the day of the month is 19 and the weather is rainy. Does that help?

Comment: So I did impossible thing. I knew I'm superman!!!

Comment: @OZ_ it is not accepted yet so you don't know yet if it answered the question. :)

Comment: Why everyone give me negative rating

Answer (score 2):

Use as few queries as possible, to execute queries your script needs to contact the SQL server every time which is much slower than the execution of code.

Answer (score 2):

Always go for the less database queries - it reduces load, and it's faster. Of course, there are exceptions to this rule (I can't think of any, though). *In general*, try to use as few database calls as possible by utilising `JOIN`s, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Few simple queries is better than 1 difficult query. Sometimes few simple queries can be united to 1 **simple** query - it's normal. But very often I see strange queries with 5-10 JOINS and sub-selects, and only reason - `BECAUSE I CAN DO THIS IN ONE QUERY!!1!`.

Also, results of simple queries often can be cached, so all you need is fetch rest of simple queries. Not all results can be cached, so difficult queries looses here.

Also, I don't like `JOIN`s (because `JOIN` =  `SLOW QUERY` very often).

Comment: joins are only slow if your tables are not indexed correctly or the data sets you are trying to join are huge (>millions)

Comment: @knittl query with `join` will be slowly than query without `join`. Query with `join` can't be used with databases, placed in different servers. Also, queries with `join` creates problems for migration to nosql storage.

Comment: @OZ: have you ever tried to get the usernames for thousands userids without a join? that's thousands of queries compared to a single query. relational databases are optimized for joins (assuming the correct indices on your tables).

Comment: @knittl no, I'm not so stupid. I just know what does `denormalization` means.

Comment: @OZ: well, sometimes you need normalized dbs, other times you need denormalized dbs. the way your answer is worded it sounds like a join is always a bad idea — which it is not.

Comment: @knittl I just answered you why I don't like `JOIN`s.

Comment: just because you don't like something does not mean it's bad. and queries containing joins are not automatically slow, if used correctly they can boost performance by quite a bit.

Comment: @knittl I also wrote a list of reasons, why `JOIN`s are bad. So now I can just say: if you like `JOIN`s, it doesn't mean that `JOIN`s are good. nosql databases can boost performance much better, than `JOIN`s.

Comment: oz: where are you many reasons why joins are bad? i can only see "i don't like joins" and "simple queries could be cached". i don't say nosql dbs are bad, they have their benefits too. but it's simply not correct to say "joins perform bad and are slow, denormalized nosql dbs are always better"

Comment: @knittl in second comment. And your last phrase is very correct, I like it.

Comment: i said »it's **not** correct to say …«

Comment: @knittl I know :) Let's stop this holywar.